# Can not import PyOpenGL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, pyopengl

I am trying to install the PyOpenGL module on my mac. But when I run `pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate` I get:

```
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade):
 PyOpenGL in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.0a3-py2.7.egg
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
PyOpenGL-accelerate in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.0a3-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
    Cleaning up...
```

Because there are no errors, and I am naive I would assume that the module has been installed.  But when I try to import anything that should come with it, like

```
import OpenGL 
OpenGL.ERROR_ON_COPY = True 
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
```

It cannot be found. 
When I try to run it I get:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/lego90511/Desktop/PyOpenGL-Demo-3.0.1b1/PyOpenGL-Demo/GLUT/gears.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lego90511/Desktop/PyOpenGL-Demo-3.0.1b1/PyOpenGL-Demo/GLUT/gears.py", line 7, in <module>
    import OpenGL 
ImportError: No module named OpenGL
```

The .egg is where it says it should be, but I can't find anything else. So where has it gone, or if the egg has not been unzipped how to I go about that?

After some more exploration I tried to unzip the .egg file. I got

```
pip unzip /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.0a3-py2.7.egg
The module /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.0a3-py2.7.egg (in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyOpenGL-3.1.0a3-py2.7.egg) is not a zip file; cannot be unzipped
Storing complete log in /Users/lego90511/.pip/pip.log
```

So then what is the .egg file?

Comment: Are you importing with the same Python as you are installing it with? What is the code you are running and what is the error message you get?

Comment: I'm using code from a PyOpenGL example, I added some of the imports above, none of them work. The interpreter is /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python It might be possible that I am pip-ing into the wrong python, but I also tried it with pip-2.7 and got the same result.

Comment: I still want the traceback.

Comment: I don't mean to sound dim but, traceback of what?

Comment: The full error message. All of it.

Comment: I tried to unzip the .egg file, and added the results uptop

Comment: Yeah, that error looks legit, that file should be unzippable. Try deleting it (and everything else in site-packages that sound like OpenGL) and reinstall it.

Comment: is there some special way to do that or will rm work?

Comment: rm will work, but try `pip uninstall` first. And I'm not a mac expert, try to verify that this isn't something that comes with OS X.